# Attempting to convert a JSON file that has a field starting with a number to a Java class

Tags: java, json, serialization, json-deserialization

this is my first time converting a Json file to a java object, namely this one: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/

Every other field works fine except the 24h_volume_usd, since I can't make a java field that starts with the 24. I looked for solutions around a bit and tried to use jackson.annotate by doing

```
@JsonProperty("24h_volume_usd")
private double volume24Hour;
```

but it's still not converting the 24h_volume_usd field from the Json file into my java class, does anyone have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy-paste and use whole Class automatically generated relating to JSON engine you are using from [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org).
For example part of generated code for Jackson 2.x is:

```
@JsonProperty("24h_volume_usd")
private String _24hVolumeUsd;
...
@JsonProperty("24h_volume_usd")
public void set24hVolumeUsd(String _24hVolumeUsd) {
this._24hVolumeUsd = _24hVolumeUsd;
}
```